# Nested Sets Categories with Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, nested-sets

I have a `categories` table

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
name
clean_name
image
description
lft
rgt
)
```

I need to be able to query all products within a category, organized by sub-categories. In other words:

```
Products
-Electronics
--Portable
>>> Product 1
>>> Product 2
--TV
>>> Product 1
>>> Product 2
>>> Product 3
```

So I'd love to be able to loop over `Electronics` and display the products within their distinctive categories...

So far, all I've been able to do is use a `raw` query to return the categories, but all on one level, and no products.

Ideally, I'd love to use `Eloquent` to manage all of this...

Comment: Could you post all your relevant database tables and relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Your questions not very clear about exactly what you have set up so far, but essentially you would want:

- a categories table with an id and name
- a products table with an id, a category_id and a name.

You then need a corresponding model for each:

```
//category model
Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}

//product model
Product extends Eloquent
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

You would then grab your categories with your products and perhaps use a nest loop like so:

```
$categories Category::with('Products')->get();
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>'
    foreach($category->products as $product)
    {
        echo $product->name
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, if not, you'll need to post some more details about what you have so far